# Not able to call function of swift from Objective-C++ code

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Swift, my class is something looks like below

```
@objc public class DemoSDK: NSObject {

public static var shared = DemoSDK()

public func connect(delegate: DemoSDKDelegate?) {
}
}
```

I call a method from the swift like below (I am trying to write an equivalent objective-c++ code of below line)

```
DemoSDK.shared.connect(delegate: self)
```

How can I call swift file function from objective-c++ code?
**I already imported header and all related classes into objective-c++ class, also all the required class and methods are marked with @objc**

*(Note: class in swift do not have constructor or initializer)*

```
DemoSDK *obj = [[DemoSDK alloc] init]; // Error 'init' is unavailable
```

Comment: The posted code does not show @objc tag on 'shared' property or 'connect' function. And there is no '@objc public init()'

Comment: Facing the same issue rn, how did you "import" the Swift file in Objective-C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add getInstance Method in swift file:

```
@objc public class DemoSDK: NSObject {

private static var shared = DemoSDK()

@objc public static func getInstance() -> DemoSDK {
  return shared
}

@objc public func connect(delegate: DemoSDKDelegate?) {

}

}
```

---

obj-C code :

```
[[DemoSDK getInstance] connect: self];
```

Comment: No known class method for selector 'getInstance' . No known instance method for selector 'connect:'

Comment: i have edited my response. can you please take a look again ?

Answer (score 1):

Mark all public classes, protocols, initializers, functions and properties with `@objc`

Comment: That I already did, but how to call a method using a static instance of class?

Comment: @harshal shows this in his updated answer: [DemoSDK getInstance].